# Check if all Ids from a list exist in database using Rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my Rails 5 + Postgres app I have a table of passengers. I select a sub-set of those passengers and store them as passengers.

```
passengers = Passenger.where(...)
```

Each passenger has an Id.

I also have a list of Ids `[1,2,3,6,8,9]`.

Now I want to check if those given Ids exist as Ids in my passengers object.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

loading all data just to check that will not be efficient specially if you have to many in the database, the best you can do is:

```
ids = [1,2,3,6,8,9]
passengers_count = Passenger.where(id: ids).count
passengers_count == ids.count
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you need to check if they **all** exist, or if **at least one** of them exists?

```
ids = [1,2,3,6,8,9]
passenger_ids = passengers.collect(&:id)
```

### Checking for all

```
def contains_all(ids, passenger_ids)
  ids.each do |id|
    return false unless passenger_ids.include?(id)
  end
  return true
end
```

or for a one-liner

`(passenger_ids & ids) == ids`

### Checking for any

```
def contains_any(ids, passenger_ids)
  ids.each do |id|
    return true if passenger_ids.include?(id)
  end
end
```

or (again!) for a one-liner

`(passenger_ids & ids).size > 0`

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, following should give you all the passengers whose id is part of your ids array

```
passengers.collect(&:id) & [1,2,3,6,8,9]
```